# I want to use vertical-align:middle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2CRZP/

I want to put the grey box in the middle of the screen using vertical-align:middle or something (CSS).

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="hero-unit">
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <p>stackoverflow</p>
        <p>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span2"><a href="./basecss.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" target="_blank">BASE CSS</a></div>
            </div>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/2CRZP/2/

You have to put this:

```
.container-fluid {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-160px;
}
```

In the margin-top you have the half of the height div in negative. (If you edit it)
And vertical-align:middle its only for TD tables. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You mean the green box ?! I don't see any gray box

If you want to use vertical-align with divs, try the display:table-cell;

http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/